# Internal USB DVD Driver reconnect

Tags: usb

I have Toshiba A665-6056 which came with an internal DVD Drive connected like a USB i.e the DVD drive can be disconnected as a normal USB from Safely remove Hardware. i don't know if that the way its suppose to be coz i have never seen an internal DVD connected via USB internally.

Now my question is how do i reconnect the dvd back after i accidentally disconnected it via Safely Remove Hardware. I don't want to Reboot my Laptop. i wonder if i can do it without reboot. Please help

Comment: you might want to check out [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/32023/how-do-i-get-windows-vista-or-windows-7-to-re-attach-a-usb-device-without-having)

Answer (score 0):

Look around the DVD drive and see if there is a screw or button you can push to remove it.  Just take it out and put it back in and Windows should automatically re-see the drive.

Comment: No button or screw, there is only eject button which does not respond when i pressed it

Comment: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/1D120A90884C25AF862573A700602459