# Automate/Simulate pulling out and plugging in USB device

Tags: usb

I have a project where an aerial collecting environmental sensor data is connected to the PC via USB. The aerial has a microcontoller which I am assuming has a lock out mode so that when power is turned on and off on the PC the microcontroller on the aerial will not start even though it is continuously plugged in. I have automated this system so that if there is a power cut and power comes back on the PC will start automatically and run the script to enable data collection from the sensors.

However the aerial will not receive data unless the USB connection is reset by pulling it out and plugging it back in. Is there anyway I can automate this on start-up whereby the USB port is disconnected and then reconnected to reset the aerial microcontroller. I want to automate a USB ejection/re-mount so it does not have to be pulled out and plugged back in manually.

Comment: Which power off-on you are talking about? Is this device "self powered" (gets its power from a separate DC supply,  or is it "bus powered", from a USB port? What is "aerial"?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be answered without the OS but Linux see https://askubuntu.com/a/290519/8023 and other answers in that topic, Windows is [How do I get Windows to re-attach a USB device without having to plug it in again?](https://superuser.com/q/32023/41259) answered , (also see https://superuser.com/a/1099688/41259 ), Mac OS X is at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/271252/23889